# SPL Token 2022 Transfer Fee

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token-program

Is there a way to retrieve the token extension fee for SolToken2022?
When we pass the Mint address, it returns the transfer fee.

**Edit:**

```
const fee = await getTransferFeeConfig(mint
  );

  console.log("fee: ", fee);

**error**
Error fetching transfer fee config: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use getTransferFeeConfig from @solana/spl-token to do this.

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/functions/getTransferFeeConfig.html

**Edit:**

getTransferFeeConfig requires the mint data as an input

You can get that using getMint from @solana/spl-token

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/functions/getMint.html

Example:

```
const tokenMintData = await getMint(
  connection, 
  tokenMintPubkey, 
  commitment, 
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
)
```

const transferFeeConfig = getTransferFeeConfig(tokenMintData)

Comment: Hi @Zombi, check the question I edited question, now using the TransferFeeConfig. Should I pass like this?

Comment: Should I send minting Address or mint Object?

Comment: Updated my answer 

Comment: TokenAccountNotFoundError- same error as I'm working on SPL2022

Comment: You'll just need to substitute `TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID` with `TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID`, but otherwise this is correct!